# then() runs first before promise.all() is resolved

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, async-await, angular6

I am using `async-await` technique to resolve the `promises` but issue is `then()` is being called first before `promise.all()` is resolved.

**Updated**

> changed from `Promise<void>` to `Promise<string>`, the result is same `then()` is being called before `Promise.all()`

```
// after uploading the image returns path
private async imageUpload(): Promise<string> {
    try {
      let img = await this.file.upload(this.imageToUpload, 'fileInput_image')
      img.subscribe((path: string) => {
        this.bg_img_url.setValue(path)
        console.log(this.bg_img_url.value) // returns url
        return this.bg_img_url.value
      })
   }
}

// after uploading the icon returns path    
private async iconUpload(): Promise<string> {
  try {
      let icon = await this.file.upload(this.iconToUpload, 'fileInput_icon')
      icon.subscribe((path: string) => {
        this.item_icon.setValue(path)
        console.log(this.item_icon.value) // returns url
        return this.item_icon.value
      })
   } 
}
```

The problem is now I am unable to get values when required

```
Promise.all([this.iconUpload(), this.imageUpload()])
      .then((x) => {
        console.log(this.bg_img_url.value) // ''
        console.log(this.item_icon.value) // ''
})
```

How to resolve `promise.all()` first before executing `then()`?

Thank you for all you spent time on my issue. really enjoyed to get different methods and suggestions. Thank you guys

Comment: Your 2 asyncs are void, shouldnt they be resolving and or rejecting? According to mdn if all of the elements of the array passed to promise.all evaluate to empty/non-reject, promise.all is considered fulfilled https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Did you return strings because of my last comment? That's still not resolve or reject.

Comment: yes, then I updated my question but still the result is same, `then()` is being called first.

Comment: Variables img, icon Observables?

Comment: simple variables of `string-type`, reactive form's fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SIMPLEST**
Actually, since subscribe is synchronous. Even this will work

```
// after uploading the image returns path
private async imageUpload(): Promise <string> {
  try {
    let img = await this.file.upload(this.imageToUpload, 'fileInput_image')
    img.subscribe((path: string) => {
      this.bg_img_url.setValue(path)
      console.log(this.bg_img_url.value) // returns url
    })
    return this.bg_img_url.value
  }
}

// after uploading the icon returns path    
private async iconUpload(): Promise <string> {
  try {
    let icon = await this.file.upload(this.iconToUpload, 'fileInput_icon')
    icon.subscribe((path: string) => {
      this.item_icon.setValue(path)
      console.log(this.item_icon.value) // returns url
    })
    return this.item_icon.value
  }
}
```

**OTHER OPTIONS**
You should either return a Promise from both functions like this

```
// after uploading the image returns path
private async imageUpload(): Promise <string> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    try {
      let img = await this.file.upload(this.imageToUpload, 'fileInput_image')
      img.subscribe((path: string) => {
        this.bg_img_url.setValue(path)
        console.log(this.bg_img_url.value) // returns url
        resolve(this.bg_img_url.value)
      })
    }
  })
}

// after uploading the icon returns path    
private async iconUpload(): Promise <string> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    try {
      let icon = await this.file.upload(this.iconToUpload, 'fileInput_icon')
      icon.subscribe((path: string) => {
        this.item_icon.setValue(path)
        console.log(this.item_icon.value) // returns url
        resolve(this.item_icon.value)
      })
    }
  })
}
```

OR the rxjs way like this

```
// after uploading the image returns path
private async imageUpload(): Promise <string> {
  try {
    let img = await this.file.upload(this.imageToUpload, 'fileInput_image')
    img.pipe(
      switchMap((path: string) => {
        this.bg_img_url.setValue(path)
        console.log(this.bg_img_url.value) // returns url
        return this.bg_img_url.value
      })
    ).toPromise()
  }
}

// after uploading the icon returns path    
private async iconUpload(): Promise <string> {
  try {
    let icon = await this.file.upload(this.iconToUpload, 'fileInput_icon')
    icon.pipe(
      switchMap((path: string) => {
        this.item_icon.setValue(path)
        console.log(this.item_icon.value) // returns url
        return this.item_icon.value
      })
    ).toPromise()
  }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented your **SIMPLEST** method, because it is similar to my implementation but could not success. Same result, then() runs first

Comment: I have returned the result right after the `subscribe()` method is finished but failing with `then()` is being called first.

Comment: I have also tested this method without `async-await` but still no success

Comment: Am I correct to assume that `this.file.upload()` returns an rxjs observable?
Either way, the second approach should work irrespective of that fact.

Comment: Yes, it returns observable

Comment: Also, maybe its a typo, but you really should at least have a `finally {}` block after `try {}` **or** just have an empty `catch {}`.  
Doesn't this code give you a compile error without it?

Answer (score 2):

Promises shouldn't be used along with async await - you need to decide about your desired approach.

**Option 1** - Just use the promise and remove the async / await decorators.

**Option 2** - Remove `then` from the promise, `await` ensures that your code will "wait" for the promises to resolve:

```
async someFunction() {
...
await Promise.all([this.iconUpload(), this.imageUpload()])
... You can use the resolved values from your promises here
console.log(this.bg_img_url.value) // ''
console.log(this.item_icon.value)
}
```

Comment: but if you look at the `return-type` of `async-await` method, it is of `promise-type` then why it is not possible to use `async-await`

Answer (score 1):

You trying return result inside subscribe method. Functions don't wait execution subscribe method. Here I see 2 Observable result and prefer use `forkJoin`, [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nkxub5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) example. Another way, return promises from Observable variables.

**example**

```
// from imageUpload
return img.toPromise();

// from iconUpload
return icon.toPromise();

Promise.all([this.iconUpload(), this.imageUpload()])
  .then((x) => {
      console.log(x);
});
```